# using bangla language in label text of kivy app

Tags: text, label, kivy

i want to add bangla text in a label. im using several font for this. here i used kalpurush.ttf. the bangla text is showing well. but some problem with sequence of bangla letter.  i wrote "তিন আস্তানা মাস্তান"।  but it shows- "ত িন  আসতানা মাসতান" its not showing the conjunct word also. and "ি"  sign should be before "ত" but here its after. I'm using pydroid app.

in kivy launcher when i use any other font than english it just crashes. so kivy launcher doesnt support any other font.

i just want to know how does bangla text look like when running it in a pc. but i have no pc.

can anoyone run this code on pc please and give me screenshot? i just need to know does bangla font shows well in kivy. cause i have to make an android app in my native language(bangla)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''

<hello>:
    Label:
        text:"তিন অাস্তানা মাস্তান"
        font_name:"kalpurush.ttf" #please download this font

''')

class hello(BoxLayout):
    pass

class go(App):
    def build(self):
        return hello()

go().run()
```

Comment: Here is a screenshot from your code run on Ubuntu 18.04 using Python 3.6.8 and kivy 1.11.0: [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rz625r3v3qrunq4/Screenshot%20from%202019-07-21%2009-15-56.png?dl=0). Running on Windows 10 produces the same.

Comment: any way to solve this issue? does python support other language or just english? i have to make an android app in my native language. but python/ kivy doesnt support bangla language in well formated! please help me solving this problem, i will be grateful to you

Comment: @ashikuzzaman: What is your OS?

Comment: i run my code in pydroid app. so os is android. and i also want to make an android app. but in pydroid app i'm getting that error(explained above) and in kivy launcher,  if i use any other language font(not english), then the code crashes in kivy launcher. so i want to know if there is any way yo solve that problem. you can also see john Anderson's comment

Comment: hello ikolim, can you help me please?

Comment: @ashikuzzaman: Please check the following posts [Issues with printing languages in unicode](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/2669) and [kivy-examples/widgets/unicode-textinput.py](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/widgets/unicode_textinput.py)

Comment: @ashikuzzaman did you find any solution regarding this problem?? I am also facing same issue

Comment: no. i didn't.  i think kivy still sucks in android development. I searched it so many days but found nothing

Answer (score 1):

We can use [font][/font] tag to use Bangla ANSI text with English text in same Label widget. Like this (in kv language):

```
    text = "[font=font/SutonnyMJ]Avwg evsjvq K_v ewj[/font] means I speak Bangla"
```

But how to generate (English and Bangla mixed) text with font tag? [This github repo](https://github.com/MS-Jahan/unicode2bijoy) provides a solution:

```
def toBijoy(str):
    def isEnglish(s):
        return s.isascii()
    import converter
    test = converter.Unicode()
    b_flag = 0
    ftext = ""
    temp = ''
    for char in str:
        if char == ' ' and b_flag == 0:
            ftext += char
        elif char == ' ' and b_flag == 1:
            temp += char
        elif isEnglish(char) is False:
            if b_flag == 0:
                temp += "কর্ড [font=font/SutonnyMJ]" + char
                b_flag = 1
            else:
                temp += char
        else:
            if b_flag == 1:
                temp = test.convertUnicodeToBijoy(temp)
                temp = temp[4:] + "[/font]" + char
                ftext += temp
                b_flag = 0
                temp = ''
            else:
                ftext += char

    return ftext
```

Now we can convert the text (with font tags), call an widget using id, and then assign formatted text.

```
self.ids.bangla_mixed_text.markup = True
self.ids.bangla_mixed_text.text = toBijoy(str)
```

In kv language we need to do something like this:

```
Label:
    id: bangla_mixed_text
    text: ''
```

More details in the repo.