# how to set label text by accessing key or value from dict

Tags: python, dictionary, kivy

i want to acces key from dict. here's a textinput. i gave that textinput an id:word. if any text from that textinput matches any of these key or value from that dict, then the text of a label should be changed to show some text.
i can access key or value from dict.

but problem is when i use if self.ids.word in Dict.keys():
then show something. but self.ids.word is a string data and any key or value from dict is Nonetype class. so self.ids.word cant be in dict. cause str cant be in dict(while dict key or value ls nonetype)

how can i do that?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import *

Dict={"my": "amar","i":"ami","you":"tumi"}


class pop(Popup):
    add=StringProperty()
    a=app.root.yo.ids.word.text
    if a in Dict.keys():
        self.add=str(a) + str(Dict.get(a))
class yo(BoxLayout):
    def pop(self):
        po=pop()
        po.open()
class go(BoxLayout):
    main=ObjectProperty(None)
    def yo(self):
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.main=yo()
        self.add_widget(self.main)

Builder.load_string('''
<go>:
    Button:
        text:"go"
        on_press:root.yo()
<yo>:
    TextInput:
        id:word
    Button:
        text:"press"
        on_press:root.pop()
<pop>:
    title:"pop"
    size_hint:0.8,0.3
    Label:
        text:root.add
```

''')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Question 2

> i want to get these
>   key and ids in a popup label. i know in kivy i should use
>   a=app.root.yo.ids.word.text. but how to access that id in py code?

### Solution

1. Implement a constructor for class `pop()`.
2. Use `App.get_running_app()` to get an instance of your app
3. use `root.main` to get an instance of your `yo` object

#### Snippets - py file

```
class pop(Popup):
    add = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(pop, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        a = App.get_running_app().root.main.ids.word.text
        if a in Dict.keys():
            self.add = str(a) + str(Dict.get(a))
```

## Question 1

> but problem is when i use if self.ids.word in Dict.keys(): then show
>   something. but self.ids.word is a string data and any key or value
>   from dict is Nonetype class. so self.ids.word cant be in dict. cause
>   str cant be in dict(while dict key or value ls nonetype)

### Solution

`self.ids.word` is a reference to the `TextInput` object. Therefore, you want to access the `text` attribute of the `TextInput` object.

Replace `a = self.ids.word` with `a = self.ids.word.text`

Comment: thanks.  but can you check my edited post again please? i want to get these key and ids in a popup label. i know in kivy i should use a=app.root.yo.ids.word.text.  but how to access that id in py code?

Comment: Please refer to updated post for solution to second problem.

Comment: [If you want to say "thank you", vote on or accept that person's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

[If you accept someone else's answer: You gain +2 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: can you give me one more solution? i asked several questions in stackoverflow. but you help me so freely and i think you are very userfriendly. i have an issue. can i share a link with you? i posted a question. i want to share the link here to get your help. can i?

Comment: Post the link to that question.

Comment: here it is.    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57130508/using-bangla-language-in-label-text-of-kivy-app

Comment: hello ikolim, please help me solving that problem. i posted that link in my previous comment

Comment: hello @ikolim,  please help me solving that problem. i replied your comment. check that link again